# Combine similar column data from two rows into one row

Tags: sql

I have query results with the following characteristics:

```
LIDCode                         Total   Domain  Region  VSE   Version       
AB02                               15   GLOBAL  CANLA    0     6943 
AB02 - 5925 CENTRE STREET SW       31   GLOBAL  CANLA   30     6943
```

I am taking data from 2 different tables, but I want to use the longer entry for the LIDCode value. This is one set of results of many. How can I combine these two rows together to get the total of the combined rows? The LIDcode value changes, so I can't use AB02 as a constant value to compare.

The result I need is:

```
AB02 - 5925 CENTRE STREET SW       46   GLOBAL  CANLA   30     6943
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Can you also give a table definition please

Comment: Please show the query you are using right now (as well as the table definition and RDBMS flavor).

Answer (score 4):

You might try something like this (as an example in SQL Server):

```
select max(LIDCode) as LIDCode
      , sum(Total) as Total
      , Domain
      , Region
      , sum(VSE) as VSE -- or max(VSE)
      , Version
from Mytable
group by left(LIDCode, 4), Domain, Region, Version
```

You may have to group by a different substring of LIDCode (first substring before space, etc.)

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc95a/1) to mess with and possibly try in another RDBMS.

Comment: This ended up working. I had to tweak it a little to hadle some wierd named LIDCodes. Thank you very much for the help in this matter.

Comment: @user1944143 glad to hear! Please upvote/mark as correct so future visitors know this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this for MySQL:

```
SELECT LEFT(LIDCODE, 4) AS LIDCODE, SUM(TOTAL) AS total, `Domain`, `Region`, SUM(VSE) AS vse, `Version`
FROM tbl
GROUP BY LEFT(LIDCODE, 4), `Domain`, `Region`, `Version`
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05601/1)